# DataTables warning: invalid JSON response when there are no records in the table. Also added empty array but records are not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter with the bootstrap data table to display the records from the database.

I am getting the error when there are no records are available in the table.

> DataTables warning: table id=employee-List - Invalid JSON response.
>   For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/1

Records are displaying when available in the table.

(**Note**: If I added empty array instated of 0 in the model then my error goes of but records are not displaying from the database.)

I tried to find out the solution on SO but none of the solutions is working for me. Can anyone assist me what's the issue with my code?

[image]

My code is,

**Script**

```
$('#employee-List').DataTable({
  language: {
    sLengthMenu: "Show _MENU_", // remove entries text
    searchPlaceholder: "Search",
    emptyTable: "No record found",
    search: ""
  },
  "ordering": false, // remove sorting effect from header 
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "scrollX": true,
  "bInfo": false,
  "pageLength": 10,
  "ajax": {
    "url": baseUrl + "/Employee_control/fetch_employeeList",
    "type": "POST"
  },
  "columns": [{
      "data": "id",
      "className": "reg_bg"
    },
    {
      "data": "name"
    },
    {
      "data": "email"
    },
    {
      "data": "mobileno"
    },
    {
      "data": "emp_id"
    },
    {
      "data": "address"
    },
    {
      "data": "action"
    }
  ]

});
```

**Controller**

```
public function fetch_employeeList(){
  $order_list=$this->Employee_model->fetch_employeeList();

// Datatables Variables
$draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
$start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
$length = intval($this->input->get("length"));

$data['draw'] = 1;
$data['recordsTotal'] = count($order_list);
$data['recordsFiltered'] = count($order_list);
foreach ($order_list as $key => $row) 
{
$action='<a href="" class="action-btn action-btn-border">View</a><a href="" class="action-btn action-btn-red-bg">Archive</a>';
$arr_result = array(
            "id" =>$row->id,
            "name" => $row->firstname." ".$row->middlename." ".$row->lastname,
            "email" => $row->email_id,
            "mobileno" => $row->mobileno,
            "emp_id" => $row->employee_id,
            "address" => $row->address,
            "action" => $action
);

$data['data'][] = $arr_result;

}
//print_r($arr_result);
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
}
```

**Model**

```
public function fetch_employeeList(){
        $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('tbl_employee');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        if($result)
      {
          return $result;
      }
      else{
          return []; //I added empty array instated of 0. Using this my error goes of but records are not displaying from the database.
      }
    }
```

Comment: Assuming you start from empty record in db, supposedly, empty array should be return only if there's no record in your db (you don't really need to expect something to display here). Otherwise, you need to `redraw` your `datatable` to get the newly added records.

Comment: @Royts, Yes, I start the empty records. I added all the data tables plugin. If there is no records in the database then it should display the "No records found". If records are available then that records should be displayed in the data table. This is the scenario I am trying.

Comment: I tried an empty array because of one the answer I found to use empty array in the model. Using empty array my error goes of but records are not displaying.

Comment: Empty array is used only when there's `no record to display`, otherwise, return the records that you got from your query.

Comment: Yes, That's correct. If there are no records then an empty array will call otherwise It will call the if query output. Can you check my code once? Is there any issue with my code?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the right data in your db? Or are your sure that you passed the response in the right format? can you show the response of your controller with data?

Comment: @Royts, Yes, I am sure, I am getting the right data. Is there any issue with data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your JSON response returned by the controller needs to always contain a property named `data`, and the way you wrote the code in the controller, you are only setting the `data` property in the response array if there are results.

In your controller, you need to default `$data['data']` to an empty array like this:

```php
$data['draw'] = 1;
$data['recordsTotal'] = count($order_list);
$data['recordsFiltered'] = count($order_list);
$data['data'] = []; // add this line in controller
```

For more information, see the [DataTables manual on server side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) (scroll down to the Returned Data section)

**Update**

In your model method, you should always return an array instead of returning `0` when there are no results. Looking at the documentation for codeigniter, `$query->getResult()` will return an empty array if there are no results, so you can update the model method to this:

```php
public function fetch_employeeList(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_employee');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: @questionbank note that I did not test this, so there could be other issues in your code as well. But you definitely need to make sure you always return a `data` property in the response, which is why you are seeing the invalid JSON response.

Comment: I added  $data['data'] = []; but still, it's giving me DataTables warning: table id=uploadedLead-list - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1         if there is no records

Comment: Can you add the raw JSON response to your question?

Comment: currently my table is totally empty, and in the network tab responsive, I am getting the error Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: Is the model still returning an empty array if there are no results? Look at your error logs or the error in the network tab response to see what file and line number the error is from, but this is a PHP error, not a DataTables error. I'm guessing it's coming from the countrol when you do `count($order_list)`

Comment: No, I removed the empty array and added zero. Should I added the empty array again?

Comment: Yes, that is your problem. You're trying to `count` an integer. You're model method needs to always return an array, so add the empty array again.

Comment: Oh! Yes, I added and now, If there are no records in the table then I am getting the " No records found" and if there is a record in the table then I am getting the records in the table list. Yes, now it's working perfectly. Thank you patrick3853.

Comment: I just want to know that, am I on the right path to display the records in the datatable? because I have more then 10k records in the table.